# How to suppress secure coding graphing warning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Matplotlib to graph a function, but Python (not Matplotlib) gives me this warning:

```
YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOUR-MIN-SEC.MILLISEC Python[10012:910102] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
```

where YEAR-MONTH-DAY etc. is the current date and time the warning happened.

I tried to use warnings to suppress the warning:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but the warnings still shows. Is there any "correct" way to suppress this?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  If so it looks like https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27389.  If you know how to consistently generate the warning, Matplotlib devs would appreciate that information.

Comment: According to the GitHub issue, it looks like it's been patched for Python 3.12. I'll upgrade Python and try again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RuthC The warning still exists for 3.12.1. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the release of Matplotlib V3.8.3, this is fixed. Thank you to everyone who contributed.